# How to compile the listener.cpp and talker.cpp without cmake

Tags: ros, std-msgs, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Upon reading the following tutorial [Simplest ROS tutorial](http://jbohren.com/articles/roscpp-hello-world/), I wanted to compile the listener.cpp and talker.cpp given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).

I am using the following command, as directed by the tutorial:

```
g++ listener.cpp -o listener_node -I/opt/ros/indigo/include -L/opt/ros/indigo/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/indigo/lib -lroscpp -lrosconsole -lrostime
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbskyfi.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3ros13serialization18throwStreamOverrunEv'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I resolve the issue and run the code?

** I did not include the message header files since they should already be included by:

```
-I/opt/ros/indigo/include -L/opt/ros/indigo/lib
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223540/how-to-compile-the-listener.cpp-and-talker.cpp-without-cmake/) by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2016-01-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The missing symbol here is  `_ZN3ros13serialization18throwStreamOverrunEv`, which comes from libroscpp_serialization.so . You should link to it by adding `-lroscpp_serialization` to you compile flags.

In general, may of the ROS packages that you'll use from C++ provide a large number of include directories and libraries, and using cmake with catkin handles the inclusion and order of these dependencies for you. It's good to understand the basics, but I strongly encourage you to use cmake on more complex projects.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6